# How can I use an Eigen::Map object for Eigen::EigenSolver?

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I have an continous OpenCV (assymmetric) matrix `cv::Mat m` and I want to compute its eigenvector and eigenvalues through `Eigen::EigenSolver`.

Since `m` could be big, making a copy through `cv2eigen` function is inefficient. Then, I want to use the `Eigen::Map`. This is my code:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> mMapped (m.ptr<float>(), m.rows, m.cols);
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>> solver(mMapped,true);//this gives a bunch of errors
```

The last line gives a bunch of errors (see the end of the question). How can I solve this? Notice that I should avoid to copy `mMapped` to a matrix object, otherwise it's equivalent to use `cv2eigen` (I think).

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >’:
../Math.hpp:64:104:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h:71:10: error: ‘Options’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >::MatrixType {aka Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >}’
     enum {
          ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues:29:0,
                 from ../Math.hpp:16,
                 from ../CloudCache.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/RealSchur.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::RealSchur<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h:312:27:   required from ‘class Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >’
../Math.hpp:64:104:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/RealSchur.h:58:10: error: ‘Options’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::RealSchur<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >::MatrixType {aka Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >}’
     enum {
          ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/RealSchur.h:14:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues:29,
                 from ../Math.hpp:16,
                 from ../CloudCache.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/HessenbergDecomposition.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::HessenbergDecomposition<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/RealSchur.h:228:41:   required from ‘class Eigen::RealSchur<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h:312:27:   required from ‘class Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >’
../Math.hpp:64:104:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/HessenbergDecomposition.h:64:10: error: ‘Options’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::HessenbergDecomposition<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >::MatrixType {aka Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >}’
     enum {
          ^
subdir.mk:30: recipe for target 'CloudCache.o' failed
make: *** [CloudCache.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare an `EigenSolver` with a `Map`, the matrix type must be a `Matrix`, so in your case:

```
typedef Matrix<float,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> RowMatrixXf;
Map<RowMatrixXf> mMapped (m.ptr<float>(), m.rows, m.cols);
EigenSolver<MatrixXf> eig(mMapped);
```

You can also instantiate `EigenSolver` with `RowMatrixXf` but the performance should be lower, despite of the transposition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So with your code that you posted above, creating `mMapped` is gonna be efficient, even if `m` is *really* big, right (hundreds of thousands of rows/cols)?

Comment: Creating `mMapped` is a no op, but computing the eigenvalues has cubic complexity, so if m=10^5 there is no way you can get the answer in a reasonable amount of time. I hope that your matrix is sparse and that your don't need all eigenvalues.

Comment: Luckily it's symmetric, so if I'm not wrong computing them should be faster

Comment: for a symmetric matrix, use `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`, but this will still require an extremely large amount of time (several days).